# TypeError: undefined is not an object only in Safari and iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, scrolltop

My below codes are working fine in Chrome but it gives the following error in Safari. Is there any solution to fix it.

```
jQuery('.mk-responsive-nav > li > a').click( function() {
   var href = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
   jQuery(window).scrollTop( jQuery("section[data-anchor='" + href + "']").offset().top );
   console.log( jQuery("section[data-anchor='" + href + "']").offset().top  );
});
```

Safari error:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'jQuery("section[data-anchor='" + href + "']").offset().top')

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say because I can't see the context html. I would recommend trying to trap the `href` variable and make sure it's actually a `jQuery Object` before scrolling the `window`. I did manage to get the same error you had.

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery('.mk-responsive-nav > li > a').click(function() {


    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
    var target = jQuery("section[data-anchor='" + href + "']");

    console.log(target.offset().top, 'YOUR EXACT ERROR IN SAFARI WHEN CLICKING FAIL LINK: ', jQuery("section[data-anchor='" + href + "']"));

    if (target.length) {
      console.log('scrolling to: ', target.offset().top);
      jQuery(window).scrollTop(target.offset().top);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mk-responsive-nav">
  <li><a href="#section-1">This will work</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#section-fail">This will fail</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<section data-anchor="section-1">Section 1.</section>
<section data-anchor="section-2">Section 2.</section>
```